# Backbone View method not firing on first load

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

When `entries/index` is loaded, it should fire `@collection.each(@appendEntry)` with appends all entries in the collection to `#entries`, but nothing happens. If I submit a new entry, everything works fine.

`entries_index.js.coffee`:

```
class Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['entries/index']

  events:
    'submit #new_entry':  'createEntry'

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('add', @render, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(collection: @collection))
    @collection.each(@appendEntry)
    this

  appendEntry: (entry) ->
    view = new Raffler.Views.Entry()
    $('#entries').append(view.render().el)

  createEntry: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.create name: $('#new_entry_name').val()
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm not sure about coffee script syntax, but how `entry` argument being passed to the `appendEntry` is used ?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `render` within `initialize`.

`@collection.each(@appendEntry)` is inside your render function, which is not being called by your view during `initialize`.

The reason you can see it after adding items is that render is being called each time an item is added to your collection, via the binding: `@collection.on('add', @render, this)`